# The first element in the created list is always 0

Tags: c++

I don't yet understand fully how linked lists and nodes in C/C++ work, but this is the function I use to add nodes to a list.

```
void AddNode(Node* head, int new_data) 
{ 
    Node* new_node = new Node(); 

    Node *last = head;

    new_node->data  = new_data; 

    new_node->next = NULL; 

    if (head == NULL) 
    { 
       head = new_node; 
       return; 
    }   

    while (last->next != NULL)
    {
        last = last->next;
    }
        last->next = new_node; 


}
```

The first element in the list will always be 0, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `head = new_node; ` This operation is pointless, since the variable is local to the function, and isn't used after the assignment.

Comment: Even if I remove this line, the result is the same.

Comment: If `head` is null, the newly allocated pointer will leak.

Comment: The problem is not that you need to remove something. You need to add something. The caller to this function needs to be aware that the list has been modified, and, as designed, it is logically impossible for that to happen. Have you learned about references, yet?

Comment: I do understand the basics of references.

Comment: @eerorika My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the function AddNode as bellow:

```
Node* head = new Node();
AddNode(head, 1);
```

And i get the same problem like you.Because the first element will never change.There are two modify
(1) return the head

```
Node* AddNode(int new_data) 
{ 
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* new_node = new Node(); 

    Node *last = head;

    new_node->data  = new_data; 
    cout << "-->" << new_node->data << endl;

    new_node->next = NULL; 

    if (head == NULL) 
    { 
       head = new_node; 
       return head; 
    }   

    while (last->next != NULL)
    {
        last = last->next;
    }
        last->next = new_node; 

    return head;
}
```

use like this:

```
Node* head = AddNode(1);
```

(2)pass the head address,because you want to change it

```
void AddNode(Node** head, int new_data) 
{ 
    Node* new_node = new Node(); 

    Node *last = *head;

    new_node->data  = new_data; 
    cout << "-->" << new_node->data << endl;

    new_node->next = NULL; 

    if (*head == NULL) 
    { 
       *head = new_node; 
       return; 
    }   

    while (last->next != NULL)
    {
        last = last->next;
    }
        last->next = new_node; 
}
```

use lie this:

```
Node* head = NULL;
AddNode(&head, 1);
```

Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the second option worked better for me since I'm using a for loop to fill the list.

You really saved me.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ , you must update 
Node *last = head;
to 
Node *& last = head;

In C, you must update 
Node *last = head;
to
Node ** last = head;